# How array in array is calculated in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, python-3.8

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.arange(9, dtype = "float").reshape(3,3)
ind1 = np.array([[1,2],[0,1]])
ind2 = np.array([[0,2],[1,2]])
arr2 = arr[ind1,ind2]
```

Hi All,

Hope you will be safe and healthy!!!

I am new to numpy, I was going through the concept of numpy and I came across the above question. I understood till the last 2nd last line but the last line I am still not able to get how it is happening?

The answer is [[3. 8.]
[1.,5.]]
The above ques was MCQ(so got the answer in hit and trial method).

Stay home stay safe!!!!

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of index arrays (not an elementary concept if you are new to numpy).  arr2 is equivalent to this:

```
arr2 = [ [arr[ind1[0,0], ind2[0,0]], arr[ind1[0,1], ind2[0,1]]], [arr[ind1[1,0], ind2[1,0]], arr[ind1[1,1], ind2[1,1]]] ]

print(arr2)
#[[3.0, 8.0], [1.0, 5.0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the `ind` arrays are (2,2) might make it harder to visualize the indexing.

```
In [41]: ind1, ind2
Out[41]: 
(array([[1, 2],
        [0, 1]]),
 array([[0, 2],
        [1, 2]]))
```

Let's ravel them - same values but in 1d:

```
In [42]: ind1.ravel(), ind2.ravel()
Out[42]: (array([1, 2, 0, 1]), array([0, 2, 1, 2]))
```

Indexing `arr` with that tuple produces the same values, but 1d:

```
In [43]: arr[_]
Out[43]: array([3, 8, 1, 5])
```

Those values are paired thus:

```
In [45]: list(zip(*Out[42]))
Out[45]: [(1, 0), (2, 2), (0, 1), (1, 2)]
In [47]: [arr[ij] for ij in Out[45]]
Out[47]: [3, 8, 1, 5]
```

Reshape that back to (2,2) to get the original indexing.

More generally, when indexing with arrays, they are `broadcast` against each other.  Those rules allow us to mix scalars, 1d arrays, and 2d arrays.  Here though the `broadcasting` is easy, since both arrays have the same shape (2,2).